# Convert singular words in a list into plurals

Tags: python

I have a list containing several singular words.

As a way to practice string slicing and list slicing, I am trying to make the singular words in the list into plural forms.

Before trying to code this problem, first create a rule like this:

A. If the end of the noun is “y”, add “ies” except for “y”.

B. If the end of the noun is “f” or “fe”, add “ves” except for “f” and “fe”.

C. If the noun ends with “s”, “x”, “z”, “ch”, or “sh”, add “es”.

D. If the noun ends with “us”, add “i” except for “us”.

E. If not in the above 4 cases, add "s".

Using the above rule, I tried to write the following code.

```py
word=[** singular word list **]
plural = []
slice = []

for i in range(0, len(word)):
    slice = list(word[i])
    result = ' '
    if slice[len(slice):] == 'y':
        slice.remove('y')
        slice.append('ies')

    elif slice[len(slice)-1:] == 'f':
        slice.remove('f')
        slice.append('ves')

    elif slice[len(slice)-2:] == 'fe':
        slice.remove('fe')
        slice.append('ves')

    elif slice[len(slice)-1:] == 's' or slice[len(slice)-1:] == 'x' or slice[len(slice)-1:] == 'z' or slice[len(slice)-2:] == 'ch' or slice[len(slice)-2:] == 'sh':
        slice.append('es')

    elif slice[len(slice)-2:] == 'us':
        slice.remove('us')
        slice.append('i')

    else:
        slice.append('s')
    
    #result = result.join(slice)
    plural.append(slice)

print(plural)
```

The problem is, the rules I set aren't working correctly.

When I run this code, The words in the list are not converted according to the rules set, and only the 's' in the else statement is attached to the word. In addition, a space is applied between characters to the output value.

```sh
['a p p l e s', 'a x e s s', 'b o o k s', 'b o x s', 'b u z z s', 'c a t s', 'c a n t u s s', 'c h u r c h s', 'd i s h s', 'k n i f e s', 'l a d y s', 'l e a f s', 'p i t c h s', 's t i m u l u s s', 't a x i s', 'w i s h s', 'w o l f s']
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You have one already plural word in the word list: ```'axes'```

Comment: you don't need to split up a string into list for this, just use the itarator. And then for each rule do slicing, for example for "y" do: `new = i[:-1]+"ies"`

Comment: You probably shouldn't name your variable `slice`. That is the name of a built-in type.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing a list returns a list, but you're comparing to a string, so the comparisons always fail.

Another problem is that `remove()` removes the *first* match, but you want to remove the letters at the end. When you do `slice.remove('y')` it will do the wrong thing if the word has another `y` in it. Instead, use slice assignment to replace the ending.

When indexing into a list, you can use negative indexes to count from the end, so you don't have to keep writing `len(slice)`.

```
    if slice[-1:] == ['y']:
        slice[-1:] = ['ies']
    elif slice[-1:] == ['f']:
        slice[-1:] = ['ves']
    elif slice[-2:] == ['f', 'e']:
        slice[-2:] = ['ves']
    elif slice[-1:] == 's' or slice[-1:] == 'x' or slice[-1:] == 'z' or slice[-2:] == ['c', 'h'] or slice[-2:] == ['s', 'h']:
        slice.append('es')
    elif slice[-2:] == ['u', 's']:
        slice[-2:] = ['i']
    else:
        slice.append('s')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly different approach. The for loop takes every word from the `word` list and checks the ending of the world using `endswith()` method. If the condition is true, it takes the part of the original word and adds a suffix based on the rules you stated in the question to the `modifiedWord`, which is then added to the `plural` list.

I also removed the already-plural word `'axes'` from the word list as I mentioned in the comments.

Here is a working code:

```py
word = ['apple', 'axe', 'book', 'box', 'buzz', 'cat', 'cantus', 'church', 'dish', 'knife', 'lady', 'leaf',  'pitch', 'stimulus', 'taxi', 'wish', 'wolf']
plural = []

for i in word:
    modifiedWord = ""
    if i.endswith("y"):
        modifiedWord = i[0:len(i) -1] + "ies"
    elif i.endswith("f"):
        modifiedWord = i[0:len(i) -1] + "ves"
    elif i.endswith("f"):
        modifiedWord = i[0:len(i) -2] + "ves"
    elif i.endswith("s") or i.endswith("x") or i.endswith("z") or i.endswith("ch") or i.endswith("sh"):
        modifiedWord = i + "es"
    elif i.endswith("us"):
        modifiedWord = i[0:len(i) -2] + "i"
    else:
        modifiedWord = i + "s"
    plural.append(modifiedWord)

print(plural)
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer